# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm just following Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorials (**Mhartl**) chapter-7 at the stage of **7.3.2 name and Gravatar**.

Here I am facing a problem when I open on my browser it's says:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with id=1
Rails.root: C:/RubyOnRails/MyWorkPlace/sample_app_1
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:5:in `show'
Request
Parameters:
{"id"=>"1"}
Show session dump
Show env dump
Response
Headers:
None
```

Also I pasted below User_controller.rb and user.rb

**user.rb:**

```
require 'digest'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :pasword
    attr_accessible :login,
                    :username,
                    :email,
                    :password,
                    :password_confirmation,
                    :remember_me

    email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

    validates :name, :presence => true,
                     :length => { :maximum => 50 }


    validates :email, :presence => true,
                      :format => { :with => email_regex }, 
                      :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

    validates :pasword, :presence     => true,
                        :confirmation => true,
                        :length       => { :within => 6..40 }

    def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
        user = find_by_email(email)
        return nil if user.nil?
        return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
    end

    before_save :encrypt_password

    def has_password?(submitted_password)
        encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
    end

    private

    def encrypt_password
        self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
        self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
        secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
        secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
        Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end                      

end
```

**users_controller.rb:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @title = @user.name
    end

    def new
        @title = "Sign up"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you created any user with id=1 ?
To check, go to rails console and get the user with id 1. If there is no user, then create one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply Aniruth, I just checked there is no user id it's says (Couldn't find User with id=1)

Comment: I tried make new used id but!!!!  ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name
        from c:/RubyOnRails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attri
butes'
        from c:/RubyOnRails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attri
bute_removal'

Comment: Open the console and type: ` @user = User.new, @user.name = "Name you want" etc., @user.save ` That should save a User with id = 1. You can  not specify the id because its a protected attribute by rails and will be handled automaticly.

Comment: yes I tried (ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attribut
es: name)

Answer (score 0):

At firest, I see you have attr_accessor :pasword

I think it should be :password

Ontopic:

There are some actions missing in the restful controller, so it wont be possible to create a user.
See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#rest for more details on RESTful controllers.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def new 
    @user = User.new #this creates a empty user object to be filled with signup data
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.new(params[:user]) #this creates a new user object with the data you entered before.
    if @user.save #if the data is valid, save it
      redirect_to user_path(@user) #and go to the @user show action
    else
      render :action => :new #edit the invalid user data
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to user_url(@user)
    else
      render edit_user_url(@user)
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id]
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end

end
```

edit: complete restful actions

Comment: `    validates :pasword, :presence     => true,` another typo!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problema. In my case, my 'redirect_to' on my detroy action was missin a 's' in 'posts_path'. It was post_path   Noob, but worth i had checked up.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you could not find the "user/1" is when you Added microposts to the sample data(db/seeds.rb) by typing

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
end
```

You forgot the "END" of the previous code, so the full picture of db/seeds.rb is

```
User.create!(name:  "Example User",
         email: "example@railstutorial.org",
         password:              "foobar",
         password_confirmation: "foobar",
         admin:     true,
         activated: true,
         activated_at: Time.zone.now)

99.times do |n|
    name  = Faker::Name.name
    email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
    password = "password"
    User.create!(name:  name,
          email: email,
          password:              password,
          password_confirmation: password,
          activated: true,
          activated_at: Time.zone.now)
end

users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
end
```