# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**when I tried to create a new user it's says**

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name
    from c:/RubyOnRails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/
 activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/
 sanitizer.rb:48:in  `process_removed_attri
 butes'
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple things:

Mass Assignment usually means passing attributes into the call that creates an object as part of an *attributes hash*. That is, you pass a bunch of attributes in a hash into the call that creates the new object. For example:

```
@user = User.create({:name => "My name", :user_type => "nice_user"})
```

However, Rails includes some basic security rules that mean *not all attributes can be assigned that way by default*. You have to specify which ones can beforehand. You do so like this:

```
class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :user_type
end
```

If you don't specify an attribute is `attr_accessible`, and you pass it in to create the object, you get the error you posted.

Here are more details:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

The alternative is to set some of the attributes when you first create the record, and set others after -- like so:

```
# In this example `user_type` is not attr_accessible so it needs to be set specifically
@user = User.create({:name => "My name"})
@user.user_type = "nice_user"
@user.save
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I added one more line on user.rb (attr_accessible :name) at present it's working, actually this is my first stage so that in future I will do exercise with above code which you have mention there, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It would have helped if your had shared the Model code.

In your model file add user to attr_accessible

```
attr_accessible :name
```

Comment: I have add the line which you have advised me then also the problem didn't solved, here is the code /
require 'digest'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :login, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :user
  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :name,  :presence => true,
                    :length => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format => { :with => email_regex }, 
          :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/application.rb`, you have the following line:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

while in your model, you miss this line:

```
attr_accessible :name
```

Do not change the config file, but add the `attr_accessible`. You should read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment to get a better understanding of the mass assignment security issue.

Comment: I have add the line which you have advised me then also the problem didn't solved

Comment: Then please add more information to your question, like the model and maybe the controller `create` method.

Comment: Christoph can you please visit this link ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292330/activerecordrecordnotfound-in-userscontrollershow ) because I have uploaded the require files